# "У него в комнате" или "в его комнате"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"У него в комнате" и "В его комнате". Какая разница в выражениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Выбор сочетания  зависит от текста.** В одном случае речь идет прежде всего **о комнате** с указанием ее принадлежности, а в другом на первом плане **хозяин** этой комнаты.

**В его комнате (где?)**

Не было Курта и **в его комнате**. [Ю. О. Домбровский. (1943-1958)]

Я нашел Озириса **в его комнате**, на любимом месте ― в глубокой нише для кровати, очень похожей на альковы в доме Дракулы. [Виктор Пелевин. (2013)]

Георгий Сергеевич уже спал, свет **в его комнате** не горел. [Александра Маринина.  (1996)]

**У него в комнате (у кого? где именно?)**

Но **у него в комнате** полно разных книг с правилами, в которых подробно описано, как и в какой последовательности отвечать одними закорючками на другие. [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)]

Когда товарищ Карабаш открыл дверь, я заметил, что **у него в комнате** была, по-моему, женщина. [Юрий Трифонов.  (1959-1962)] 
**У него в комнате** я видел доску. [Юрий Трифонов.  (1959-1962)]

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что выражение "в его комнате" указывает на принадлежность некой "комнаты" к "нему", а в выражении "у него в комнате" нет прямого указания на принадлежность, то есть, это может быть чья угодно комната, но в ней есть нечто подразумевающееся, что может относиться к "нему".
В разговорной речи употребляются оба варианта, а в письменной лично я бы использовал второй - "в его комнате", звучит лаконичнее.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взглад, есть небольшая смысловая разница. Говоря "Я был у него в комнате", я выделяю то, что был у него, а говоря "Я был в его комнате", я выделяю то, что был в комнате, которая принадлежит ему. Если сказано "В его комнате протекает потолок", то он может быть и ни при чем (уехал), а если сказано "У него в комнате протекает потолок", то он, скорее всего, живет там с этим протекающим потолком.